# Highlight all traces connected to a component in Altium?

Tags: altium

I have a chip that I'm testing voltages on. I can highlight the chip by alt-clicking on it, at which point the pads are highlighted. At this point, is there a command to highlight everything these pads are connected to? As opposed to looking up each trace one by one in the schematic.

Using a simpler component as an example, I'd like to click on a resistor and see the highlighted traces emanating from both pads, to another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on component > Component actions > Select Component Nets (highlights all nets, routed or unrounted). Select Component Connections will only highlight physically routed connections from the component. This is explained in the [Altium Documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-cmd-selectselect-ad).

Comment: I suppose there's no way to do this in 3D view? The option is greyed out in 3D mode, says "available in 2D".

Comment: @jfwork I would assume not since 3D mode doesn't allow selecting tracks to my knowledge.